# How to union two arrays with ordering?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I have a few arrays I want to union, but I need to keep them in order.
Example:

```
var js_files = [
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
'assets/scripts/**/*.js'
];
```

and:

```
var js_files = [
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js'
];
```

and I want union them and make sure the fist array will stay first & remove duplicate values.

expected outotput:

```
['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js']
```

Can I do this using _.union? Any other idea?

Comment: why don't you just `concat` them?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @tanmay concat will not handle duplicate values.

Comment: @AmitT., please add this information to the question, because it is important for it.

Comment: @choz added to the question. thank you.

Comment: @AmitT. Do concat.. The answer is already down there.. And yes, you can also use `_.union`..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the ES5 fashion using Array.prototype.slice eg :

```
const first = [1,2,3,4];
const second = [5,6,7,8];

const results = [].concat(first.slice(), second.slice());
```

Or the ESNext fashion using "desctructuring"

```
const first = [1,2,3,4];
const second = [5,6,7,8];

const result = [...first, ...second];
```

Edit : I missed the point that you need distinct values;

This will remove dupes from results after you concatenated stuff.

```
const distinctResults = results.filter(function removeDuplicates(item, index){

  return results.indexOf(item) === index;
});
```

Comment: Why not just `results = first.concat(second)`?

Comment: @Burimi `concat` can't handle duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in combination with the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for unique items in original sort order.

```js
var js_files1 = [
    'abc',
    'def',
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
    'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
    'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
    'assets/scripts/**/*.js'
  ],
  js_files2 = [
    'def',
    'ghi',
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js'
  ],
  uniqueFiles = [...new Set([...js_files1, ...js_files2])];

console.log(uniqueFiles);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];

var Joined = [...a,...b];
```

Similarly can do for your code.

Answer (score 0):

just use **Array.prototype.concat**

```js
var js_files1 = [
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
'assets/scripts/**/*.js'
];
var js_files2 = [
'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js'
];
var res = js_files1.concat(js_files2);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `concat` can't handle duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`_.union` will remove duplicate values from your second array.

In your case you dont have any duplicate value in second array so it will simply concat them

But if you have any duplicate value in second array, `_.union` will remove it

for eg.

```
 var a = [
   'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
   'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
   'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
   'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
   'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
   'assets/scripts/**/*.js'
 ];


var b = [
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js'
];
```

`_.union(a, b)` will result in

```
 [
    "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js",
    "bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js",
    "bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js",
    "bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js",
    "assets/scripts/**/*.js",

    "parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"
 ]
```

Here you can see `_.union` removes duplicate value `"bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"` of array B in the result

Comment: with `_.union` How I can control the order of the returned array? for now it returns the array ordered by the ABC.

Comment: You can't control the order, to control the order you need to write separate function depending on your requirement

Comment: Also please mention the required order of returned array in question... Right now"  _.union will return the expected output as you mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

```js
var js_files1 = [
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
'bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery-placeholder.js',
'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js',
'bower_components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js',
'assets/scripts/**/*.js'
];

var js_files2 = [
'parnet/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'parent/bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js',
"assets/scripts/**/*.js"
];

js_files2.forEach(value => {
  if (js_files1.indexOf(value) == -1) {
    js_files1.push(value);
  }
});

console.log(js_files1);
```